# Click on modal element with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

i want to click on email login button with puppeteer that are inside a modal.  But it is not working. Code is not finding any modal element. i want to automate login process. Anyone can help to debug this code

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  console.log('Launching browser...');
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
  });

  console.log('Creating new page...');
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36");

  console.log('Navigating to website...');
  const response = await page.goto('https://bikroy.com/?login-modal=true&redirect-url=/', {
   waitUntil: 'load',
   timeout: 0
  });
  await page.waitForSelector('.modal-overlay--3cs8Z', { visible: true });
  await page.click('.gtm-email-login', { visible: true });
  await page.waitFortimeout(4000);
  console.log(`Website loaded with status code ${response.status()}`);
  /**
  console.log('Navigating to website again...');
  await page.goto('https://ourcodeworld.com', {
    waitUntil: 'load',
    timeout: 0
  });

  console.log('Doing stuff...');
  // Do your stuff here...
  **/
  console.log('Closing browser...');
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that consent modal in intercepting your click.

You should close it first (or disable if you have access to site and know, how to do it, pass some cookies, etc.)

This code works for me with your scenario

```js
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
    });

    console.log('Creating new page...');
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setUserAgent(
      'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36',
    );

    console.log('Navigating to website...');
    await page.goto('https://bikroy.com/?login-modal=true&redirect-url=/', {
      waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded',
    });
    const consentSelector = '.fc-consent-root button.fc-primary-button';
    await page.waitForSelector(consentSelector).then((c) => c!.click());
    await page.waitForSelector(consentSelector, { hidden: true });
    const modal = await page.waitForSelector('[data-testid=modal-node]', {
      visible: true,
    });
    await modal!
      .waitForSelector('.gtm-email-login button')
      .then((b) => b!.click());
    await page.waitForSelector('.gtm-email-signup');
```